# Extract text from .tex files using Tika

Tags: tex, text-extraction, apache-tika

How do I extract text from a `.tex` file using Apache Tika?  An example file is at http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/EulerGibbsDuhem.tex

Tika is able to correctly detect the content type as `application/x-tex` but does not extract anything from it.

I tried the command

```
java -jar tika-app-0.9.jar -t EulerGibbsDuhem.tex
```

and also the following code snippet:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mimeType = tika.detect(file);
pageContent = tika.parseToString(file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tika supports detecting the .tex file extension, but there isn't a parser for it yet, sorry.

If you can find a good Java library (ideally Apache Licensed) for parsing .tex files, then I'd suggest you open a new enhancement request in the Tika JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA) and request a Tex Parser based on that library.

Comment: Thanks, if I find such a library, then I will open a ticket.